# Menu icon is not displaying in action bar

Tags: android, android-fragments, menu, android-actionbar, menuitem

I need to inflate custom menu in Fragment.

I have only one menu item.But the icon is not displaying.

Can someone tell what is wrong with my code

My menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"  >

<item
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_search_category_default"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="Search"/></menu>
```

And I set in onCreateView()

```
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
```

And inflating the menu

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    inflater = getActivity().getMenuInflater();

    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

}
```

Resulting screen attached below. I need to have the search icon instead of the menu overflow icon.

[image]

Comment: Try `app:showAsAction="always"` to your menu Item

Comment: Thanks Panther, even i add " app:showAsAction="always" ", it is not showing the icon, See my edited question

Comment: can you try to change your icon.?

Comment: Try image from project's drawable instead of android:drawable. May be not getting image from android:drawable.

Comment: I tried to change my icon from my drawable folder, still it is not working

Answer (score 10):

I know I'm a little late for the party, but hope I can help someone else. Today I was facing this SAME problem.

I fixed using android:showAsAction="always" instead of app:showAsAction="always"

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item android:id="@+id/bluetooth_status_off"
    android:orderInCategory="0"
    android:icon="@drawable/bluetooth_red"
    android:title="@string/app_name"
    android:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

on the showAsAction is underlined with red (warning), but works fine.

Answer (score 2):

**I Think You should use**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"  >

<item
android:id="@+id/search"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_category_default"
app:showAsAction="always"
android:title="Search"/></menu>
```

**and**

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mymenu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Pamitha , I tried it... It is not working :(

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to late but put this code in your onCreate()

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the following property `app:showAsAction="ifRoom"`

Comment: Thanks hoomi, even i add " app:showAsAction="always" ", it is not showing the icon, See my edited question

Comment: try removing `getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();`

Comment: also remove `inflater = getActivity().getMenuInflater();` and see if that helps

Comment: Note that @hoomi is suggesting to use `app:showAsAction="ifRoom"`, NOT `app:showAsAction="always"` as you said you tried and @Panther suggested above. I think if you try `ifRoom` it will work.

Comment: I tried both ifRoom and Always , still it is not working

Comment: Try a different drawable like your `ic_launcher.png`

Comment: Also trying putting `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` in `onCreate`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure, you've added a menu item without an icon.
Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/next_btn"
        android:checked="true"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
        android:title="Item"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="Settings" />

</menu>
```

Thanks to action_settings, it'll automatically add an overflow icon.

Answer (score 0):

make a menu  with the code below...

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
   <item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"/>

   <item 
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:title="Search"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />
 </menu>
```

and set it as your menu..

Comment: put something in strings of your wish. and give the reference here in title. and select a icon.. paste it into drawables and give the reference in icon.

Answer (score 0):

This is default behaviour of the Overflow menu from the ActionBar.
If you want to show the Icons in the overflow menu, override the onMenuOpened method in your activity with this code snippit:

```
@Override
public boolean onMenuOpened(int featureId, Menu menu) {
    if(featureId == Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR && menu != null){
        if(menu.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("MenuBuilder")){
            try{
                Method m = menu.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(
                        "setOptionalIconsVisible", Boolean.TYPE);
                m.setAccessible(true);
                m.invoke(menu, true);
            }
            catch(NoSuchMethodException e){
                Log.e("MyActivity", "onMenuOpened", e);
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }
    return super.onMenuOpened(featureId, menu);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're running your code on Android 3.0+, the icons in the menu are not shown by design.
This is a design decision by Google.
[You can read more about this on Android developers blog.](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html)

Comment: Links may become stale, could you summarize some of the key points or (appropriatly) cite relevant parts of the blog?

Answer (score 0):

1. Copy your menu xml code.
2. Delete your menu file
3. Now create a new menu file in res->menu directory
4. And name it with different name
5. Now Run